# How to call method from another class in Swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, nsnotificationcenter

I am working an an app that involves a wheel. I want to execute a function in another class when the angular velocity reaches 0 after being spun.

The setup is that I have a SKView embedded in a view controller. I have a class called WheelView that is tied to that SKView.

Full class: https://github.com/swiftishard/wheelpractice2/blob/master/WheelView.swift
This is the relevant portion of code.

```
class WheelDelegate: NSObject, SKSceneDelegate {



func didSimulatePhysics(for scene: SKScene) {

    guard let wheelScene = scene as? WheelScene else { return }
    if (wheelScene.wheel.physicsBody?.angularVelocity ?? 0.0) > 0.0 {
        print(wheelScene.wheel.physicsBody?.angularVelocity)
        if(wheelScene.wheel.physicsBody?.angularVelocity ?? 0.0) < 25.0 {
            wheelScene.wheel.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = 0.0
            if(wheelScene.wheel.physicsBody?.angularVelocity ?? 0.0) == 0.0 {

                print("CALL METHOD FROM ANOTHER VIEW CONTROLLER")

            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Main view controller where method to call is located

```
  import UIKit

class Main: UIViewController {
    func methodToCall() {
        print("METHOD CALLED")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


}
```

So how would I call `methodToCall` from the didSimulatePhysics code?

Comment: Do you create WheelDelegate views from Main VC?

Comment: In the main VC, I have a button that executes a function to spin.                                                                                                                         @IBOutlet weak var wheelie: WheelView!                                                                               func stupidWheel() {
        let random_number = Int(arc4random_uniform(39) + 20)
        wheelie.wheel.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = CGFloat(random_number)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `WheelDelegate` is created within `Main` as an object.

Multiple ways you can do this:

**1) Most common way I have seen is to create a protocol as well as some delegates.**

Inside `Main` class, right below all the imports, you can do.

```
protocol ViewControllerTalkingDelegate {
    func methodToCall()
}
```

Inside `WheelDelegate` you add this as a global variable

```
var delegate:ViewControllerTalkingDelegate?
```

Then, whenever you create `WheelDelegate` inside `Main`

```
let wheelDelegate = WheelDelegate()
wheelDelegate.delegate = self
```

Then, inside `Main` at the bottom, you can do

```
extension Main:ViewControllerTalkingDelegate {
    func methodToCall() {
         //Do Something
    }
}
```

Now, inside `WheelDelegate` you can do `delegate.methodToCall()`.

**2) Other way I have seen is to pass the 1st class as a variable to the 2nd class.**

Inside WheelDelegate add a global variable

```
var myViewController:Main?
```

You can then either take in `Main` as a parameter when initializing or when you create `WheelDelegate` you can do

```
var wheelDelegate = WheelDelegate()
wheelDelegate.myViewController = self
```

Then inside `WheelDelegate` you can do

```
self.myViewController.methodToCall()
```